# Nativescript gestures not working with vuejs

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How to use them? Docs are not clear about vuejs, only pure js.
I tried to add

```
var gestures = require("tns-core-modules/ui/gestures");
var labelModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/label");
var label = new labelModule.Label();
label.on(gestures.GestureTypes.tap, function (args) {
    console.log("Tap");
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work - not logs in the console.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> First of all,run `tns -v` and check your NS version.
> `tns-core-modules` is an old way of importing things. For **{N} v7**:
> `@nativescript/ui/gestures` Check out [new import rules](https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-import-reference/)
>
> As a general rule, If you are using nativescript-vue then you should
> check typescript code samples.
>
> ````js
> "tns-core-modules/ui/gestures"; ```
> ````

### Gestures in nativescript-vue

There is nothing to import to use gestures.

```html
  <Label
    text="REFRESH"
    @swipe="refresh"
  />
```

or

```html
  <Label
    text="REFRESH"
    @doubleTap="refresh"
  />
```

Unfortunately, nativescript docs are currently outdated for nativescript 7.